# System.Convert.ToByte

Tags: character-encoding, asp-classic

Hi is there any equivalent method in classic ASP for C#.net function "System.Convert.ToByte" ?

basically i am encoding one string in my windows app using c#. and in classic asp it need to be decoded in which it need to use the above function.

Thanks,
Vinod

Comment: Can I ask why you're converting strings into bytes at all? Strings in C# are, I believe, encoded internally as UTF-8 and will display correctly in on any web page with encoding set to UTF-8 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm missing something important here but how about int=Val(ch) and ch=Chr(int)?

Also and as I'm sure you already know, converting the characters in a C# string into bytes will fail for any string containing anything outside of the extended ASCII range, i.e. 00=NUL to FF='ÿ'.